# website translation with .htaccess and friendly url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have a website called website.com/example/index.php with a directory called example inside root (root / example / index.php ). So far i have:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/example/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /example/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Now I want to add translation to my website in spanish. In index.php I call the english version via a href="?lang=en_US" and spanish via a href="?lang=es_ES" so in my browser url I get http://website.com/example/?lang=es_ES when switching to Spanish. My question is how do I make the url show: website.com/es/example/index or any page without having the physical directories en or es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|es)/(.+?)/?$ /example/$2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is assuming all your URLs have en or es in them and that all your scripts in /example/ can accept the GET-variable lang. The $1 refers to the language and QSA means query string append so that if a user accesses /example/somepage?somevar=1, somevar still gets passed to $2.

Note that your second RewriteCond doesn't make sense since $1 is not defined yet.

Comment: Yes this put me on the right track now I got it to work thanks for the reference on .htaccess as this is still new to me.